# Union query wrong execution

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, union

I'm trying to execute the query below but the problem is that it shows execute a bunch of nonsense what I want it to show those who are female dependent and there associated employee first name  ....... where is my failing point + I have to use union operator

```
 SELECT Dep_FName AS 'First name' ,Dep_LName AS 'Last name'  ,Em_FName AS 'Employee"s First name'
 FROM evnt_db.dependent,evnt_db.employee
 where Dep_gender='F' 
Union SELECT Dep_FName AS 'First name'  ,Dep_LName  AS 'Last name'  ,Em_FName AS 'Employee"s First name'
 FROM evnt_db.dependent as d,evnt_db.employee as e
 where d.Emp_Id=e.Em_Id ;
```

Comment: When you execute the second part, do you get results? Do you double checked?

Comment: Maybe try removing the parenthesis around the Select statements. I'm not sure this is the problem but the Union(Select part does not look right to me.

Comment: Your column name aliases do not match up and they have to for a UNION statement. 'Last name ' has a space at the end of the first one, but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Union only selects distinct values, so maybe it is filtering overlap out. Also I don't know why you need to use Union for this statement since you are selecting from the same table. You could just use an OR in the where of the first half of the query.

```
SELECT Dep_FName AS 'First name ',Dep_LName AS 'Last name '  
 FROM evnt_db.dependent
 where Dep_gender='F' OR Relationship='Wife';
```

If you must use UNION, this should work. I think you query had something weird with the parenthesis. Also the column names have to be identical in a UNION statement. There was an extra space on `'Last name '` and not on the other `'Last name'`

```
SELECT Dep_FName AS 'First name ',Dep_LName AS 'Last name '  
 FROM evnt_db.dependent
 where Dep_gender='F'
UNION
SELECT Dep_FName AS 'First name ',Dep_LName  AS 'Last name '  
 FROM evnt_db.dependent
 where Relationship='Wife';
```

If you want to get the duplicate records (prevent union from filtering duplicates), use `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`

Comment: I think you are right, but to select duplicate values OP could use UNION ALL.

Comment: Yeah, I should add that as an alternate answer

Comment: yah thank you I did try that and it worked but in the requirement for the project is implementing the union operator ..... so the union operator is only for two different tables ??

Comment: You can use the union operator for the same table, but an OR is better I think.

Comment: UNION ALL still is UNION. That's the way you want to go.

Comment: Kevin, you can edit your answer whenever you want :)

Comment: still the same :(((

Comment: I just noticed another error where the column aliases did not match. That may have prevented results from the second part of the query from showing. I edited my answer.

Comment: Does the second query run on its own and get results?

Comment: Looks like you have the same problem where there is a space after the first 'Last name ' but not the other. Column aliases must be identical in a UNION statement. Just add a space to 'Last name'

Comment: i edited the union to something else please help me with that

Comment: What's wrong with it now? Do both selects execute properly on their own? Get both of them to find results when they execute properly on their own before trying to put them together with a UNION.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` by default removes duplicate result rows, if you want those duplcates you can use `UNION ALL`.

If you don't want those duplicates, your current query already takes care of that; though you should also consider Kevin's answer in that case.

In any case, you should only expect to see results from the latter query if you have dependent rows that are non-'F' wives.